# What does it mean for a function to be $C^0(S^1)$?

Tags: analysis

And how would you interpret the convolution $f\ast g$ for $f,g \in C^0(S^1)$.

Comment: Please define $C^0$ and $S^1$. Do they denote the set of continuous functions and the unit sphere or disk?

Comment: For $X$ a topological space, $C^0(X)$ is the set of continuous functions $X\to \mathbb R,$ unless otherwise specified. Convolution on a measurable compact group $G$ can be written as $$(f*g)(h)=\frac{1}{\mu(G)}\int_{h_1\in G} f(h_1)g(hh_1^{-1})\,d\mu.$$ Since $S^1$ is a compact topological group, this gives you both. In particular, $f*g$ exists for any $f,g\in C^0(S^1).$

Comment: You can think of $f,g\in C^0(S^1)$ as the set of all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x.$ Then given $f,g,$ you have $$(f*g)(x)=\int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(x-t)\,dt.$$ You obviously need to prove that $f*g\in C^0$ if $f,g$ are.